# Jquery fadeIn/fadeOut animation issues

Tags: jquery, effects, fadein, transition, fadeout

I am using Jquery FadeIn/FaeOut to show and hide content on my page. Like so:

```
$('.subnav_company').click(function(){
                    $('.aboutcontent').fadeOut('slow');
            $('.company').fadeIn('slow');           
                    });
```

My problem is that because the div '.company' is positioned below '.aboutcontent' when '.company' is shown it appears below '.aboutcontent' until the div has hidden fully, creating a unsmooth transition effect.

How can I make the transition between showing and hiding the divs smooth? Not jumpy. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="aboutcontent developers">
<h1>Developers</h1>
<h4>The developers are the best</h4>
<p> we have some great developers</p>
</div>
<!--End aboutcontent developers-->


    <div class="aboutcontent company">
    <h1>Company</h1>
    <h4>offers a complete management tool . It's an easy to use and efficient way to manage and plan  stuff. It allows people to communicate and get along.</h4>
    </div>
    <!--End aboutcontent company-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the callback for [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), like this:

```
$('.subnav_company').click(function(){
  $('.aboutcontent:visible').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('.company').fadeIn('slow');           
  });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/SE6dK/), this won't trigger the [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) on `.company` until the fade on `.aboutcontent` is complete.

Since you're fading out many panels, some of which are already hidden, it's important to use the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) so the callback only triggers after the fading one, not instantly from the one who's fade completes instantly...because it's already hidden.