# How to fadeOut one div and fadeIn another div with jquery timing?

Tags: jquery, html

Thanks to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668412/jquery-fadein-fadeout-animation-issues), I can get a div to fade-out after 3 seconds. 
But I can't get a second div to fade-in after 3 seconds - that div is already on-screen from zero. The code is:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#blue').delay(3000).fadenOut(100);
    $('#red').delay(3000).fadeIn(100);
  });
```

Demo: [http://www.casedasole.it/stack/](http://www.casedasole.it/stack/index.html)

The idea is to have div 1 (blue) dissolve and reveal div 2 (red).

Please note: I've offset div 1 to show how div 2 is "always there". I need to hide div 2 because in testing, div 2 appears before div 1 covers it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `display:none;` in #red's styles, so that it'll be hidden when you open the page initially.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#blue').delay(3000).fadeOut(100);
   $('#red').delay(3000).fadeIn(100);
 });
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: yellow
}
#red {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #f00;
  display: none;
}
#blue {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: #00f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - http://www.casedasole.it/stack/fixed.html (I must wait 6 minutes to accept answer)

Answer (score 1):

I would insert a .hide at the beginning, like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#blue').delay(3000).fadenOut(100);
    $('#red').hide().delay(3000).fadeIn(100);
});
```

Comment: It could be done this way, but until the page is fully loaded, the red div will still be visible.

Comment: It works (after fixing typo "fadenOut"): http://www.casedasole.it/stack/tomas.html

Answer (score 1):

JQUERY SOLUTION, TRY THIS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#blue" ).delay(3000).fadeOut( 100, function() {
         $('#red').fadeIn(100);
    });
 });
```

With adding `display:none` to `#red` as one suggested.

here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h2dpou63/)

Comment: The OP wants to fadeOut the first div, while fading in the second.

Comment: Updated with what meant to suggest actually.